# Realm Platform get Realms owned by user

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to fetch Realms that are owned by a logged in user (full sync).

```
currentUser().getPermissionManager().getPermissions(new PermissionManager.PermissionsCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(RealmResults<Permission> permissions) {

                RealmResults<Permission> results = permissions
                        .where()
                        .findAll();

                for (Permission result : results) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + result.getPath());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ObjectServerError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onError: "+error.getErrorMessage());
            }
        });
```

But what I get is:

```
/myUserId***/__permission
/myUserId***/__perm
```

When i look at the console (Realm studio) I see that my users have 4 Realm paths, 3 of the paths I don't know where from:

```
/~/__permission
/~/__perm
/~/__management
```

1. From where are these paths?
2. Why does my real Realm, that was created, not appear in the result?

I guess the permissions are granted because my Realm is synchronized with the server and all changes synced as well.

EDIT: when the user login is not set as admin the results contain all projects.

Comment: `/~/` represents "the current user's id" i think.

Comment: yes its correct